# How do I wire this light switch?

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

[image]
[image]
In particular I don’t know what to think of the gray wire. Most resources online suggest gray is neutral. If I treat gray as black I would go black to black, grey to red, red to red/white, green to ground based on the instructions.

Comment: We need to know what the model number of the switch is so we can look up it’s obscure color codes. The part in the wall is pretty easy to see what is what.

Comment: Added pic. Really my main confusion is the gray cable from the wall and if that can be safely assumed to be a black. If so things match the instructions pretty well.

Comment: As pointed out your grey is really a black.  Your current switch isn’t 3-way, so you’ll want to follow the single pole diagram, which is likely to cap the red/white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's an off-spec black

That "gray" wire is really a black wire that is off-spec a bit on color, as NM does not come with gray wires in it (or pink for that matter, so the "pink" wire is really a red wire).

Comment: Ahhh! I see what he’s calling gray now.  I had to click the pic and blow it up to understand the confusion.